# How to prevent keyboard from moving the view up when it is already shown

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift4, uikeyboard

I got the keyboard to move up when I click a textfield but as soon as I click another textfield It move the view up even more. Thank you for your help.

```
func keyboardStates() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: 
UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
#selector(keyboardWillChange(notification:)), name: 
UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification){

    guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {

        return
    }

    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification {
        view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRect.height/3
    } else {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be a simpler way, but from memory, I just used a "flag" which is set to true when `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` is raised and reset when `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` is raised.  This simply stops my "show" handler from executing it's functionality until the "hide" handler is called

Answer (score 2):

Try the below method,

```
@objc
    func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else { return }
        guard let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? UInt else { return }
        guard let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
        guard let endingFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
        let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keyboardHasShown = false 

@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification){

guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {

    return
}

if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification {
    if keyboardHasShown == false {
      view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardRect.height/3

   }
    keyboardHasShown = true
} else {
    view.frame.origin.y = 0
    keyboardHasShown = false
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well doing it per view controller basis will be difficult and time consuming, i would recommend to use this fantastic library for such tasks, it supports, scroll view, table view and collection view.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Give it a try and i assure you will like it too.

Regards,
Harish